# Как установить iTunes на linux?

Tags: linux

Никак не могу установить iTunes, помогите, что делать-то?

Через WINE не получается. Потом подумал, что можно установить виртуальную машину, но и тут тупик. Мне недавно поставили Linux, так что я еще не разобрался.

Comment: Этот вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию.

Comment: ifuse для копирования медиа с айфона вполне пригодно.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще это вопрос на [БитКод](http://user.hashcode.ru). А устанавливается просто, для примера на Ubuntu. Сначала устанавливает [Wine](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/wine). Затем грузите [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/). Затем выполняете из консоли:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
chmod +x iTunesSetup.exe
wine iTunesSetup.exe
```

Далее - по шагам мастера.

Comment: БитКод умер, я даже войти не могу, а последний вопрос был задан год назад.

Answer (score 2):

Поставь gtkpod Кроссплатформенный многоязыковой интерфейс для Apple iPod™ и получишь доступ к своему устройству без вайна

Answer (score 0):

Linux вообще-то, а не Ubuntu! Отвечавшему выше. По теме - найди страницу программы на http://appdb.winehq.org/ Кроме того, с айподом умеют работать плееры Amarok, rhytmbox, deadbeef и Banshee.